# How much do you think SO is worth?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, business-model

Let's say someone is going to buy SO and all its property, how much do you think it's worth?

Comment: Wasn't this asked once before?

Comment: I think we should track down Atwood, shake him upside-down then buy SO with whatever lunch money falls out of him.

Comment: @Gargamel: Can't we just cut out the middle man and shake him upside-down until SO falls out?

Comment: @Pesto: SO is software, man. He keeps that on a set of 54 floppies in his desk. No one can carry around that many floppies.

Comment: @Gargamel: What if he has a backpack?  Or a large fanny pack?  Or he's pushing a shopping cart?

Comment: Backpacks and fanny packs have zippers, and so shaking him upside-down won't cause SO to fall out. Likewise, a shopping cart is not attached to Atwood, and so flipping him upside-down will not upturn the cart. What we *could* do is glue his hands to the shopping cart before inverting his orientation and agitating him.

Comment: You're assuming that he keeps his backpacks and fanny packs properly zipped, a point I'm not willing to concede without evidence.  Even if that is the case, we simply need to shake him vigorously enough to cause the zipper to open.  And as to the shopping cart, perhaps I assumed too much, but I took it for granted that we would permanently attach his hands to said cart prior to inversion.  My mistake for not clarifying that, I suppose.

Comment: I would pay extra to keep silly questions about site worth out of here.

Comment: Where did he get the shopping cart, backpack and fanny pack? If he got them at Wal-Mart, then the cart's handle will be covered in sticky juice residue and the packs' zippers will fail at the slightest hint of internal pressure. But if he got them from, say, Kool-Aid mail-in points, then we are well and truly welbogged. Those things are impenetrable zippered fortresses and the Kool-Aid shopping cart has rocket booster on the back; we'd never catch Atwood on one of those things.

Comment: On a related note, Stack Overflow is worth sixty million Kool-Aid mail-in points.

Comment: @Gargamel: The Kool-Aid points program has been discontinued, so we're probably in the clear. Unless, of course, Jeff knows the Kool-Aid Man personally, in which case we are ubersmurfed. No wall can protect you from the Kool-Aid Man.  He will forever quench our thirst, holding our heads beneath the churning amethyst waves of a sea of Purplesaurus Rex, until at last we cease to struggle. When we surface again, we shall be no more than soulless revenants shuffling across the Earth in search of the thirsty, that they too may know the quenching of undeath. Jeff, as a vampire, is naturally immune.

Comment: @Pesto: What if we just give the Kool-Aid man like $5 to punch Jeff in the gut?

Comment: @Gargamel: But who will we shake upside-down to get the $5?

Comment: Nice try, Mr. Trump.

Comment: $ 230,947,200.00 - https://statvoo.com/website/stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Good question!  How big a problem is SO, and how can we convince the industry at large to buy out Jeff et. al. before all of our productivity is sucked away?  Perhaps we should multiply the average time a user spends on SO by the average IT person's salary and the number of users.

For illustrative purposes, if we're conservative and we say there are:

- 10,000 regular users
- Averaging 5 hours a week on SO
- Paid an average US$25/hr

That's US$1,250,000 per week.  Therefore, SO has cost **US$65 million** in lost productivity in the past year alone.  It must be worth that much to close it down, for all our sakes, *before it's too late*!

Comment: You forgot to account for time spent on sock puppets, futile as they are. Calculating that makes my head hurt, so +1.

Answer (score 26):

According to http://www.websitevaluecalculator.com/ it is worth

## $127!

Comment: For comparison, ponyoverflow.com is worth $103.

Comment: Wow... my blog is worth almost half that! I'm almost half as good as Stack Overflow!!! w00t

Comment: welbog.homeip.net is worth $97! I'm going to strike it rich!

Comment: Superuser is worth $119! That's almost as much as Stack Overflow! We have to stop it!

Comment: Right on! Meta is worth $119! I always knew this website was worth something.

Comment: codinghorror.com is worth $127.  joelonsoftware.com?  $136!  If J&J sold all their sites maybe they'd have enough for a pony.  (Gawds, this is a funny site.)

Comment: I tried to find out how much websitevaluecalculator.com was worth using websitevaluecalculator.com and it exploded!

Comment: Good Lord, man -- according to these yo-yos, my site (with 2 pages, lazily built in iWeb because I shut down my blog and didn't want to bother) is worth $95 -- 2/3 the value of SO?

Comment: This, determined through an advanced algorithm, surely: Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Empty string supplied as input in /home/website/public_html/ThumbnailUtility.php on line 31

Warning: fopen(/home/website/public_html/IMGCACHE/stackoverflow.com.jpg) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/website/public_html/

Comment: My blog, which sees only moderate traffic has 5,251,030 backlinks!!! SO has 5,345,000 .. woot! I'm catching up!! And I'm valued almost as high!

Comment: Rats.  I thought we had a way to get rid of the US national debt, but house.gov and senate.gov are only worth $152.  whitehouse.gov is better at $188,769 but still not enough.

Comment: @tinkertim, I saw that too.  And I laughed.  Then I checked it out, and apparently, http://www.websitevaluecalculator.com/ is worth $33,042

Comment: @Ewan: No kidding? When I did it, it was $27K. Nice to be able to increase in value so quickly!

Comment: I think all the linking to it here has driven up it's value

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure what it's actually worth, but it's very likely Google will buy it for a few billion dollars, give it away for free, and somehow get even richer by doing it.  Those guys are evil wizards, I tell you!

Answer (score 14):

1 Billion dollars - *pinky in corner of mouth*

Comment: One Million, or One Hundred Billion.

Comment: you misspelled *"beeeellion"*

Answer (score 10):

Whatever somebody's willing to pay for it.

Comment: We all know logic doesn't apply on the internet. :)

Answer (score 10):

Probably about three fitty.

Comment: Really? I could get a pizza for that! I can't EAT SO, so I know which I'd rather have.

Comment: How much is that in America moneys, Canada Boy?

Comment: @Pesto: About two fitty.

Comment: @Pesto: Considering our economic woes, it could be quite a lot. ;)

Comment: Hey that's not even enough for a Flatizza. Outrageous.

Comment: Well, it was about that time that I noticed this @XMLbog was about eight stories tall and was [a crustacean from the plethazoic era](http://youtu.be/9cn7xfBpZ3M)!

Answer (score 6):

http://www.websiteoutlook.com/www.stackoverflow.com

$3.84 million or 44.72 million pesos.

That's a lot of franks and beans...

Comment: it's up to $3.84M now

Comment: up to $4.13M now...

Comment: Four years later, ten times as much. This algorithm seems legit.

Comment: 10 years later.... 34 mil

Answer (score 4):

What currency we talking about here? 
The real question is of course what it will be worth in 6 - 8 weeks?

What about theoretical dollars?  Sneezing Panda is worth billions!

Comment: -1 because I hate pandas.

Comment: This new upvote/downvote viewing feature is really nice. haha

Comment: And on the halftime it's 3-1 for Manchester United.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth $42, not more, not less.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking of a number between

#### *enough to cover Jeff's mortgage*

and

#### *enough to cover Jeff's mortgage, the next three mortgages, and five new cars*

Comment: Hey, share your `~` secret with us?

Comment: @jjnguy http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25542/me-no-likey-no-tilde

Comment: Thanks! more characters....more and more and more ...

Comment: That ~ is becoming quite a bit of a celebrity, isn't it?

Comment: and here i was thinking of changing it.  oh well, no Autobiographer badge for me.... :p

Comment: Badges are overrated. ~ are not!

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I found out this results too ([source](http://websitestatschecker.com/www/stackoverflow.com)):

> Stackoverflow.com is worth $ 390,447,000

Do you think it's that much?

Comment: Heh. It's a wild unfounded guess posing as an "estimate". It's not really a reliable number.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.I found a website link: 
http://www.worthofweb.com/website-value/stackoverflow.com

It is giving following price.
$ 2,957,500,000

Comment: Those kind of sites are completely useless.

Comment: ya i guess so. But the price is really nice i guess.