# How can I get some details about Stack Exchange's finances?

Tags: discussion, support

**What is the net worth of Stack exchange network and the Stack overflow?**

A website [claims](http://www.worthofweb.com/website-value/stackoverflow.com/) that [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) is worth $2.8 billion and SE network is [worth](http://www.worthofweb.com/website-value/stackexchange.com/) $1 billion, is it true that SO is much bigger than the whole of SE network itself?

Comment: [How much do you think is SO worth](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31374/how-much-do-you-think-so-is-worth) is a related one, but it is very old.

Comment: That site doesn't rate how much companies are worth, it lists guestimates (at best) about how much add revenue a website could gather. To get the SE "value", you'd need to add all the individual site's "worth"s.

Comment: Related: [What is Stack Overflow's business model?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model)

Comment: @anshabhi I wouldn't expect any better answer, despite it being old...

Comment: @Mat not really. For example, if you write "aviation.stackexchange.com" or some other website, then the worth is $937mn only!

Comment: @anshabhi: you still need to add all the sites that aren't in `*.stackexchange.com`, _including_ SO, to get SE's whole "worth", assuming that site's listings are in any way reliable.

Comment: @Mat yes but.. I am considering SO different from SE just for his question..

Comment: Voting to leave open. "How can I get details on SE/SO's finances" is objectively answerable; the answer is that you can't. The "What is the net worth" part should be removed.

Comment: Find out how much an [careers post](http://i.imgur.com/JzzMNb7.jpg) costs. Find out [advertising costs](http://stackexchange.com/mediakit). Calculate the per day rate for each. Guess at how many advertisements and career posts are visible on a given day. Multiply advertisement and career post counts by 365. Profit.

Comment: Agree with @S.L.Barth, this question is on topic here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard closing this is okay, but how do you have moderation privileges? What is that gold badge following your name?

Comment: @anshabhi http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders?lq=1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Though I am an employee of Stack Exchange, these are my views and are not to be taken as official.

> How can I get some details about Stack Exchange's finances?

You can't. Stack Exchange is privately owned and doesn't divulge financial information publicly.

> What is the net worth of Stack exchange network and the Stack overflow?

An item is only worth what someone is willing to pay for it. Once someone is willing to pay for Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange, we will all learn what they are worth.

If you are talking about how much the company is worth (assets, money in the bank etc...), then this information is not publicly available and will not be, so long as the company is privately owned.

> A website claims

You shouldn't believe everything you see on the web. If you read through to their "methodology", you will see this is an estimate of how much ad revenue a site can produce. Does that correlate with how much a site is "worth"?

> is it true that SO is much bigger than the whole of SE network itself?

In terms of traffic, that is not the case - the rest of the network is getting more traffic than Stack Overflow gets by itself.

I don't really know what metrics you are using for "bigger" though.

Comment: by "bigger" I mainly mean traffic only..

Comment: -1 for "You shouldn't believe everything you see on the web" :)

Comment: @gnat You just created the believer paradox... a variant of the liar paradox. :-)